Introducing Coroutine in a callback builder pattern
I would like to refactor some code that uses callback style into Coroutine one but I'm wrapping my head around.
The code looks like the following:
fun authenticate(/* parameters */) {
    val builder = // Obtaining the builder
    builder
      .withCallback(getAuthenticationCallback()) 
      .build()

    // Using the builder
}

where getAuthenticationCallback is defined as:
private fun getAuthenticationCallback(): AuthenticationCallback {
    return object : AuthenticationCallback {
        override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult: AuthenticationResult) {
            
        }

        override fun onError(exception: AuthenticationException) {

        }

        override fun onCancel() {
            
        }
    }
}

Since the creation of the builder cannot be modified (not my code), I can act just on the suspend fun authenticate and on the second part of the code.
Is there a clean way to modify the code by using Coroutine? I was thinking on passing the CoroutineScope as parameter but I'm not sure if it's the correct way.

You're looking for suspendCancellableCoroutine, which provides extensive documentation about how to handle cases pretty much exactly the same as the one you have.

A good way to cleanly handle the callbacks is to convert them to a Flow:
fun authenticate(/* parameters */): Flow<AuthState> = callbackFlow {
    val builder = builder
        .withCallback(getAuthenticationCallback())
        .build()

    // Using the builder
    doSomeStuffWithBuilder(builder)

    awaitClose {
        // cleanup here, for example:
        //  * unregister listener
        //  * close resources
        //  * whatever else is necessary
    }
}

This returns of flow of callback results.
Although authenticate is no suspend function, the callbackFlow's lambda is, and it will only be executed as part of a coroutine. We come back later to it to see how exactly that is done.
The general idea is that everything that should be done with builder happens here (or in doSomeStuffWithBuilder(builder) to make the code easier to read). awaitClose at the end suspends the execution even when doSomeStuffWithBuilder is finished so potential callbacks that come at some later point in time won't get lost. It's lambda is executed when the callbacks are no longer needed and can be used for cleanup. Can also be empty if nothing needs to be cleaned up.
Now to the interesting part where the actual callbacks are converted to values of a flow. We need to change getAuthenticationCallback like this:
private fun ProducerScope<AuthState>.getAuthenticationCallback(): AuthenticationCallback =
    object : AuthenticationCallback {
        override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult: AuthenticationResult) {
            trySendBlocking(AuthState.Success(authenticationResult))
        }

        override fun onError(exception: AuthenticationException) {
            trySendBlocking(AuthState.Error(exception))
        }

        override fun onCancel() {
            trySendBlocking(AuthState.Cancelled)
        }
    }

Whatever you previously did in these callbacks should return their result as an AuthState object:
sealed interface AuthState {
    data class Success(val authenticationResult: AuthenticationResult) : AuthState
    data class Error(val exception: AuthenticationException) : AuthState
    data object Cancelled : AuthState
}

This data structure is something that I just came up with, feel free to adapt it to whatever you need.
I said the callbacks need to return such an object: They obviously cannot return it as a function return because you have no control over the AuthenticationCallback interface. That is not important, though, because we use trySendBlocking instead. Note that I changed getAuthenticationCallback to take a ProducerScope as a receiver. This scope provides various send methods, choose what suits you best (e.g. trySendBlocking). The actual scope that is used here is provided by the callbackFlow's lambda where we call getAuthenticationCallback. All values sent are emitted into the Flow that is returned from callbackFlow.
Finally, let's see how this new authenticate function is used.:
val flow = authenticate(/* parameters */)

flow.collect {
    when (it) {
        is AuthState.Success -> TODO()
        is AuthState.Error -> TODO()
        is AuthState.Cancelled -> TODO()
    }
}

As already stated at the beginning, authenticate is not a suspend function and it immediately returns a flow.
You can then collect the Flow's values. Now this is a suspend function, so it must be called from a coroutine. And only now the callbackFlow's lambda is executed in this coroutine.
The nice thing about Flows is that you can collect them from anywhere in your program. After calling authenticate, everything necessary is contained in the returnd flow object and you can pass that around to wherever it is needed. As soon as a terminal operator (like collect) is called, the flow comes to life, does some stuff and listens for callbacks. When the collection is cancelled, the flow is also automatically cancelled and the awaitClose lambda is executed.
If, for example, you have a UI, the flow could (and should!) be collected there. You would need to pass the flow up into the UI, while, on the way, possibly applying any of the various transformation functions on the flow like mapLatest, onEach, etc. or even combine it with other flows. More on flows can be found in the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html
As a side note, this might be relevant since a lot of Kotlin code with a UI is part of an Android app: In that case you would pass the flow to your view model and convert it there to a StateFlow by using stateIn with viewModelScope as a parameter. Then you would use the Compose function collectAsStateWithLifecycle in the UI to retrieve the flow's values. This isn't even a suspend function anymore, it chooses an appropriate coroutine scope under the hood to collect the flow.
